# I am unable to resolve Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a need to learn to display a query in a pivot table. I was able to resolve all but one issue. When entering valid dates, the query runs properly. But I need the query to be dynamic but passing dates via variable to a string. I have included both the working query and the one that presents the issue.
I have tried all or the available options I could find on previously asked questions but to no avail.

Working query

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @startdate as datetime = '2020-07-19 00:00:00'
    DECLARE @enddate as datetime = '2020-07-25 00:00:00'

    ;

    WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
    (
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @enddate
    )
    SELECT @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DateData,101)) +','
    FROM DateRange
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames,LEN(@ColumnNames)-1)----------removes final comma

    SET @sql =

    'SELECT * FROM
 
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10),dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked,101) AS DateWorked, 
                      dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login AS     Employee, 
                  SUM(dbo.TimeInOut.HoursWorked) AS Hours
                 FROM dbo.TimeInOut 
           INNER JOIN dbo.TimePunche ON dbo.TimeInOut.TimepuncheID = dbo.TimePunche.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Location 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Employee ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.Employee.LocationID ON dbo.TimePunche.EmployeeID = dbo.Employee.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.JobDescriptions ON dbo.TimeInOut.JobDescriptionID = dbo.JobDescriptions.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.LocationJobDescriptions ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.LocationID 
                  AND dbo.JobDescriptions.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.JobDescriptionID

               WHERE (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= ''7-19-2020'') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= ''7-25-2020'') 
                 AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''House Keeping/Sanitation'') 
                  OR (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= ''7-19-2020'')  
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= ''7-25-2020'') 
                 AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''Guard Shack'')
            
            GROUP BY 
            CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked, 101), 
                                 dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login) AS BaseData'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Query presenting issue

```
 DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @startdate as datetime = '2020-07-19 00:00:00'
    DECLARE @enddate as datetime = '2020-07-25 00:00:00'

    ;

    WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
    (
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @enddate
    )
    SELECT @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DateData,101)) +','
    FROM DateRange
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames,LEN(@ColumnNames)-1)----------removes final comma

    SET @sql =

    'SELECT * FROM
 
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10),dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked,101) AS DateWorked, 
                      dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login AS     Employee, 
                  SUM(dbo.TimeInOut.HoursWorked) AS Hours
                 FROM dbo.TimeInOut 
           INNER JOIN dbo.TimePunche ON dbo.TimeInOut.TimepuncheID = dbo.TimePunche.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Location 
           INNER JOIN dbo.Employee ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.Employee.LocationID ON dbo.TimePunche.EmployeeID = dbo.Employee.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.JobDescriptions ON dbo.TimeInOut.JobDescriptionID = dbo.JobDescriptions.ID 
           INNER JOIN dbo.LocationJobDescriptions ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.LocationID 
                  AND dbo.JobDescriptions.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.JobDescriptionID

               WHERE (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= ' + @startdate + ') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= ' + @enddate + ') 
                 AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''House Keeping/Sanitation'') 
                  OR (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= ' + @startdate + ')  
                 AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= ' + @enddate + ') 
                 AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''Guard Shack'')
            
            GROUP BY 
            CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked, 101), 
                                 dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login) AS BaseData'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I don't see why you're using dynamic SQL here. The query appears static and you can use variables directly in queries. But if there's a reason I'm missing, you should use the functionality of `sp_executesql` to take and replace parameters in the query instead of string concatenation. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments).

Comment: And just FORGET you ever learned about "top (100) percent" - it does nothing useful. And if the order of rows in your resultset is important, then your query must contain an order by clause. Grouping might introduce an order you think you can rely on - but that is an artifact of the database engine and how it processes the query. Eventually the order will not be the same as the grouping columns.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to concatenate datetime values with string values without using CAST() or CONVERT().

As already mentioned in comments you could do this with a parameterized query since you're already invoking sp_executesql, e.g.:

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (MAX) = ''
DECLARE @startdate as datetime = '2020-07-19 00:00:00'
DECLARE @enddate as datetime = '2020-07-25 00:00:00';

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @enddate
)
SELECT @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DateData,101)) +','
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames,LEN(@ColumnNames)-1)----------removes final comma

SET @sql =

'SELECT * FROM

(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
CONVERT(varchar(10),dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked,101) AS DateWorked, 
                    dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login AS     Employee, 
                SUM(dbo.TimeInOut.HoursWorked) AS Hours
                FROM dbo.TimeInOut 
        INNER JOIN dbo.TimePunche ON dbo.TimeInOut.TimepuncheID = dbo.TimePunche.ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Location 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Employee ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.Employee.LocationID ON dbo.TimePunche.EmployeeID = dbo.Employee.ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.JobDescriptions ON dbo.TimeInOut.JobDescriptionID = dbo.JobDescriptions.ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.LocationJobDescriptions ON dbo.Location.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.LocationID 
                AND dbo.JobDescriptions.ID = dbo.LocationJobDescriptions.JobDescriptionID

            WHERE (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= @1) 
                AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= @2) 
                AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''House Keeping/Sanitation'') 
                OR (dbo.Location.Name = N''PFG-City of Industry'') 
                AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked >= @1)  
                AND (dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked <= @2) 
                AND (dbo.JobDescriptions.JobDescription = ''Guard Shack'')
        
        GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.TimePunche.DateWorked, 101), 
                                dbo.Employee.LastName + '', '' + dbo.Employee.FirstName + '': '' + dbo.Employee.Login) AS BaseData'

-->>-- Note the @params definition of @1 and @2 as datetime types here...
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@1 datetime, @2 datetime', @startdate, @enddate;
```

Comment: After adding your response and the pivot I was looking for I am able to display the results I am looking for. Thank you very much. I am now trying to incorporate the results into an SSRS report. But failing miserably. 
When I paste the query in a report, I am not able to include the fields. Or get any results